# Getting "Not a legal OleAut date" error with AutoFitColumns function in EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I'm exporting some data to Excel using the EPPlus library. After writing the data to the cells, I call the AutofitColumns function. This throws an error:

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.; Not a legal OleAut date.;
STACK: at System.DateTime.TicksToOADate(Int64 value)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.FormatValue(Object v, ExcelFormatTranslator nf, String format, String textFormat)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.AutoFitColumns(Double MinimumWidth, Double MaximumWidth) at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.AutoFitColumns()
at ExcelHelper.SetExcelSettings(ExcelWorksheet& aSheet, Int32 AutoFilterRow, Int32 AutoFilterColumn, Int32 ColNumber, Int32 ColWidth)
at RLog.Export(Int32 aOfficeID, Boolean aInco...
```

It seems to be caused by a specific value in the data, because it works for other ranges of data. But I cannot figure out which exact data. Also, I can't understand why AutoFitColumns has to call FormatValue.

Any idea as to what can cause this? Here is the code:

```
Public Shared Sub SetExcelSettings(ByRef aSheet As ExcelWorksheet, Optional AutoFilterRow As Integer = 0, Optional AutoFilterColumn As Integer = 0, Optional ColNumber As Integer = 0, Optional ColWidth As Integer = 0)
    ' Apply formatting to excel
    If aSheet.Dimension IsNot Nothing Then
        With aSheet
            '.View.ShowGridLines = False
            If AutoFilterRow > 0 Then .Cells(AutoFilterRow, 1, AutoFilterRow, aSheet.Dimension.End.Column).AutoFilter = True
            .Cells(.Dimension.Address).AutoFitColumns()  ' Error happens here

            ' Wrap the text for Remarks fields
            .Cells(.Dimension.Address).Style.WrapText = True
            .Cells(.Dimension.Address).Style.VerticalAlignment = Style.ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center

            ' Set the specified width and auto wrap for specified column
            If ColNumber > 0 Then .Column(ColNumber).Width = ColWidth : .Column(ColNumber).Style.WrapText = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Have posted the code

Comment: Apparently something you export with EPPlus that Excel perceives as a DateTime value/Date column has invalid data (e.g. empty) that can't be converted into a `Date` value and consequently formatted accordingly. So I'd have a look at the **export** side of things and make sure that the exported data fits the data type Excel expects. As for your question why Excel calls FormatValue: most likely it needs to know the length of the _formatted_ data to size the columns properly.